# Fastest way to do meta query when I don't need the actual posts, and just need post_id?

Tags: meta-query

In wordpress I often use $wpdb to just do my queries manually when I just need to extract some value.

In my case, I have a Membrepress rule that could be tied to some content type. The rule's meta includes two keys that I am trying to query on: `_mepr_rules_type` and `_mepr_rules_content`.

I know I can do something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'memberpressrule',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'key' => '_mepr_rules_content',
            'value' => 885,
            'compare' => '='
        ),
        array(
            'key' => '_mepr_rules_type',
            'value' => 'single_sfwd-lessons',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    )
);
$results = new WP_Query($args);
```

But it seems overkill when I simply want the rule id.

I see that Wordpress is constructing the query as

```
SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_mepr_rules_content' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '885' ) 
  AND 
  ( mt1.meta_key = '_mepr_rules_type' AND mt1.meta_value = 'someruletype' )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'memberpressrule' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_author = 34 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

Is there any reason to deal with WP_Query? I mean, I really don't want to deal with resetting global $post and other headaches that one ends up with when using queries inside an existing post loop. So would doing this manual query be the fastest way?

```
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT   wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON ( wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND ( 
  ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_mepr_rules_content' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value = '885' ) 
  AND 
  ( mt1.meta_key = '_mepr_rules_type' AND mt1.meta_value = 'someruletype' )
) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'memberpressrule' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_author = 34 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC"
$results = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

Also, any reason why I need to join on wp_posts, if the wp_postmeta table itself contains the data I need?

Curious if anyone has ideal method to extract the sort of data I am trying to retrieve.

Thanks!

Comment: You have a property for that, you can add it to the `$args`, `'fields' => 'ids'`, this will return only the ids.

Comment: returning the IDs will make it a little faster but not by much, the problem is that it has to figure out which posts to return and that's the slow part, not the retrieving the rest of the post. This would be many times faster if `_mepr_rules_type` had been a custom taxonomy instead of a custom post meta. Remember, post meta is optimised for finding meta when you already know the post ID, it had bad performance for searches with `meta_query` that gets worse as the site gets larger, that's why tags and categories are in taxonomy tables, which are optimised for finding/filtering posts

Comment: Good to know - too bad plugins don't make more use of designs that lend themselves to faster search. Though I suppose I could make minor tweaks to enable the use of custom taxonomies in my case.

Comment: In addition, it may help a little to use get_posts() rather than WP_Query, as it'd be a bit faster in this situation. See @Pieter Goosen's answer here for a clear explanation of that: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts

Comment: Just did some tests with QP_Query vs $wpdb->get_results, and am finding $wpdb->get_results is about 7-8 times faster in my case.